# "Slim" directed polytopes: any established name for them?

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, posets, polyhedra

This is a "looking for context" question.

Let's say that a polytope is directed if its 1-skeleton is an oriented graph with no cycles, one source, one sink. (Edit: let us additionally assume that every face also has one source, one sink.) In this case, the vertices form a poset, and we can extend this poset structure to a (non-reflexive) relation on all the faces, by saying $F_1 < F_2$ if $\max (F_1) \leq \min (F_2)$. Then we can consider face-chains with respect to this new relation (notice that a vertex is comparable with itself so a vertex can repeat in a chain, while bigger faces can't). For a face-chain $(F_1 < \ldots < F_n)$ inside the face $F$, let's say that its *dimension gain* is $(\sum \dim F_i - \dim F)$. Note that dimension gains can be both positive and negative. Now, the definition:

**Definition.** A directed polytope is *slim* if a chain of length $n>1$ has dimension gain at most $n-2$.

**Examples.** Simplices and cubes with standard directions are slim. Associahedra with Tamari directions are slim.

Has this condition appeared in the literature previously?

Comment: Is the orientation coming from a generic linear functional? Without further assumptions, the fact that there is an overall minimum and maximum in your poset does not imply that each face has a minimum and a maximum.

Comment: Ah, good point! I will edit my question: I meant that the condition "one source, one sink" is brutally required from all the faces as well.

Comment: Note that the orientations from linear functionals will satisfy this condition (and are maybe a reasonable place to start thinking about it...)

Comment: By the way, "thin" is a term of art in the area (see e.g. https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82377898.pdf), which might be confused for your term "slim."

Comment: Oh, thanks for telling! Maybe I should call them "short" or "tight".

Comment: Eppstein's "treetopes" sound close (but not identical) to your concept: Eppstein, David. "Treetopes and their graphs." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 64, no. 2 (2020): 259-289. [Springer link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-020-00177-0).

Comment: One more comment- you might be interested in the "facial weak order" on the permutohedron: https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03158

Comment: "Tight polyhedron" is an existing term.  See for example my book, section 30.3.  It means something else, of course.  https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/book.htm